# jQuery - getting position() of the li within ul

Tags: jquery, position

I'm trying to figure out how to get the left position of the li relative to its ul parent tag.
Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the `ul` tag the `li`'s offset parent by giving it `position: relative`. This will allow you to call [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) on the `li`, which will tell you what you want to know.

```
var pos = $("#target").position();
$("#target").text("This li is positioned " + pos.top
                + "px from the top and " + pos.left
                + "px from the left edge of the ul");
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/p9ef9/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the `.offset()` of the `li` with the `.offset()` of the `ul` or `.parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get this using jQuery's .position().

```
$('li').position()
```

More info here:
http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: yes - but I'm trying to get the position of the li rather then ul tag

Comment: @Jon has already provided the answer - li on its own without having relative positioning on the ul tag will return position relative to the document rather than ul.